# cffi equivalent of ctypes "in_dll()"?

Tags: python-cffi

When accessing framework dlls on MacOS, which often have a lot of string constants defined, with ctypes I can do something like this to retrieve an arbitrary one at runtime, without having to define them all:

```py
CFString = c_void_p
CFStringRef = POINTER(CFString)
my_dll = CDLL(...)
s1 = CFStringRef.in_dll(my_dll, "kSomeSpecificConstant")
s2 = CFStringRef.in_dll(my_dll, "kSomeOtherConstant)
```

With cffi, I can do something like this to explicitly define things:

```py
my_dll = cffi.FFI()
my_dll.cref("""
    typedef void *CFTypeRef;
    typedef CFTypeRef CFStringRef;
    extern CFStringRef kSomeSpecificConstant
    extern CFStringRef kSomeOtherConstant
""")
```

but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to do a runtime lookup for a symbol in the way in_dll() does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API mode (`ffi.set_source()`) it is not directly possible to do runtime lookups after the `ffi.set_source()` and `ffi.compile()` are done.  In ABI mode (`lib=ffi.dlopen()`) you could do it by calling `ffi.cdef()` again to declare the symbol, and then I'm pretty sure it can be immediately accessed via a previously-returned `lib`.  It's a bit of a hack but it should work.  There are also ways to do it by invoking directly some internal functions in the CFFI runtime, but again only in ABI mode (in API mode we have no dynamic handle to the DLL in the first place; indeed there is not necessary a separate DLL at all).

But the proper way to do dynamic symbol lookups is to do it in the same way as you would in C: by using standard library functions like `dlsym()`.  With CFFI you would do it by adding the declaration `void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol);` to the `ffi.cdef()`, and related functions starting with `void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flags)`.  Check the man pages for details on MacOSX; there may be differences between these standard POSIX functions and the way they are used for frameworks on Mac.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Catching an exception on access, adding the symbol with cdef(), and trying again actually came to mind, but as you say, it seemed a bit of a hack.  I assume then that additional cdef() calls can be made after the ffi.dlopen().

I'll look at setting things up with dlsym - thanks again for the, um, pointer... :)

Comment: Given "mydll" as having come from a ffi.dlopen(dllpath), that had a cdef() defined for "dlsym", is there a way to get the dll handle from "mydll" to pass to dlsym()?  Something like:
symbol = mydll.dlsym(mydll.get_the_handle(), "someSymbolName")
It looks like the FFILibrary class effectively hides the "backendlib" it is created with, where I think the handle would be?  Or do I have to dlopen and dlclose my own handle?

Comment: You'd have either to use `ffi.cdef("...")` with some constructed string, which is a bit slow but done only once per symbol, or you have to use `dlopen()` to get your own handle independently of cffi's.  That's at least what I thought about; maybe you can hack around the `backendlib` but that's really digging into the undocumented, unsupported internals of cffi.